After running Apache Airflow in Docker can't extend it to requirements - No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'
I have launched docker container with Apache Airflow and it's working. Now I am trying to extend all necessary dependencies and here's the issue I'm faced with. My Dockerfile
FROM apache/airflow:2.9.2
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -U pip setuptools==66.0.0 wheel
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements.txt 

My requirements
numpy == 1.21.1
scikit-learn==0.24.2

Here are full logs that I get after docker build . --tag extending_airflow:latest
DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.097MB
Step 1/6 : FROM apache/airflow:2.9.2
 ---> 940b05c86097
Step 2/6 : COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cdbd62a1ecf5
Step 3/6 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a37904cc8177
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install -U pip setuptools==66.0.0 wheel
 ---> Running in 7889e762ddd9
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (24.1.2)
Collecting setuptools==66.0.0
  Downloading setuptools-66.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Downloading setuptools-66.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.3/1.3 MB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 65.8/65.8 kB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 66.1.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-66.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-66.1.1
Successfully installed setuptools-66.0.0 wheel-0.43.0
Removing intermediate container 7889e762ddd9
 ---> 846892fcfde1
Step 5/6 : RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 719d1f76c572
Collecting numpy==1.21.1 (from -r /requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading numpy-1.21.1.zip (10.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.3/10.3 MB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 174, in __bool__
    return any(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 162, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 53, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
                ^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 185, in _make_candidate_from_link
    base: Optional[BaseCandidate] = self._make_base_candidate_from_link(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 231, in _make_base_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 303, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 235, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 314, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 527, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 642, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 72, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 56, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._install_build_reqs(finder)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 126, in _install_build_reqs
    build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 103, in _get_build_requires_wheel
    return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 709, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 321, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pyproject_hooks._impl.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-bki2bnvu/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six import PY3, string_types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'

The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c pip install -r /requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2

DEPRECATED: The legacy builder is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
            Install the buildx component to build images with BuildKit:
            https://docs.docker.com/go/buildx/

Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.097MB
Step 1/6 : FROM apache/airflow:2.9.2
 ---> 940b05c86097
Step 2/6 : COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cdbd62a1ecf5
Step 3/6 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a37904cc8177
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install -U pip setuptools==66.0.0 wheel
 ---> Running in 7889e762ddd9
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (24.1.2)
Collecting setuptools==66.0.0
  Downloading setuptools-66.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Downloading setuptools-66.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.3/1.3 MB 1.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 65.8/65.8 kB 4.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 66.1.1
    Uninstalling setuptools-66.1.1:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-66.1.1
Successfully installed setuptools-66.0.0 wheel-0.43.0
Removing intermediate container 7889e762ddd9
 ---> 846892fcfde1
Step 5/6 : RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 719d1f76c572
Collecting numpy==1.21.1 (from -r /requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading numpy-1.21.1.zip (10.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.3/10.3 MB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 179, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 67, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 174, in __bool__
    return any(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 162, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 53, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
                ^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 185, in _make_candidate_from_link
    base: Optional[BaseCandidate] = self._make_base_candidate_from_link(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 231, in _make_base_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 303, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 235, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 314, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 527, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 642, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 72, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 56, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._install_build_reqs(finder)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 126, in _install_build_reqs
    build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 103, in _get_build_requires_wheel
    return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 709, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 321, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pyproject_hooks._impl.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/tmp/pip-build-env-bki2bnvu/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six import PY3, string_types
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'

The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -o errexit -o nounset -o nolog -c pip install -r /requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 2

I get an error, saying that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six' . Trying to explicitly download setuptools in Dockerfile didn't help. How do I fix this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78706627/7976758

The issue isn’t with Docker, but with your Python version. Python 3.12 only supports NumPy version 1.26.0 and above. To resolve this error, upgrade your NumPy package to version 1.26.0 or higher.
